# What's the right way to define the style of the images inside my gallery div?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a div with an id of 'gallery' and I want to style the images inside it. Specifically, I want to give each of the images a 1px solid yellow border except on the bottom because they sit on top of each other, so I don't want to double the border on the bottom.

What I'm confused about is how to choose between the different border style elements: border, border-style, border-width. I tried this:

```
div#gallery img
{
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border: solid yellow;
    border: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
```

I managed to get a yellow border with this css above but the border seems more like a 2px border - it's quite thick - and, besides that, the syntax I'm using doesn't look very elegant.

Any recommendations on how to do this more concisely/elegantly?

Comment: if "border" comes after any other border-whatever, all the previous border-whatevers will be overridden, since "border" defines all of the border properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the best way:

```
border: 1px solid yellow;
border-bottom: none;
```

The syntax for the [`border`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) declaration goes `width style color` and affects all four borders. After that, you can override the bottom back to using no border by declaring [`border-bottom`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-bottom.asp) as none.

Comment: Ah!! So border-width, border-style, border-bottom, etc can be used to override elements of 'border'. Thanks. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if there's a wrong way to do it, but you basically have 3 methods to do it:

**Method 1**

```
border-top: 1px solid yellow;
border-right: 1px solid yellow;
border-left: 1px solid yellow;
```

**Method 2**

```
border: 1px solid yellow;
border-bottom: 0;
```

**Method 2**

```
border: 1px solid yellow;
border-bottom: none;
```

I would prefer either method 2 or method 3.

(I know method 2 and method 3 are basically the same, but I wanted to give both solutions, so you can choose what you like, "none" or "0").